# How to merge two list of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

my first list is

```
"networks":[
{"name": "public", "ip_ranges":[["172.16.0.2", "172.16.0.126" ] ], "id": 173,…},
{"name": "management", "ip_ranges":[["192.168.0.1", "192.168.0.254" ] ],…},
{"name": "storage", "ip_ranges":[["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.254" ] ],…},
{"name": "private", "ip_ranges":[["192.168.2.1", "192.168.2.254" ] ],…},
{"name": "public", "ip_ranges":[["172.16.0.2", "172.16.0.126" ] ],…},
{"name": "management", "ip_ranges":[["192.168.0.1", "192.168.0.254" ] ],…},
{"name": "storage", "ip_ranges":[["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.254" ] ],…},
{"name": "private", "ip_ranges":[["192.168.2.1", "192.168.2.254" ] ],…},
{"name": "fuelweb_admin", "ip_ranges":[], "id": 181, "meta":{"notation": "ip_ranges",…},
{"name": "fuelweb_admin", "ip_ranges":[["10.30.0.3", "10.30.0.254" ] ], "id": 1,…}
]
```

and 2nd dict is like this

```
 "network_conf": [

            {
                "network_name": "default",
                "public": {
                    "ip_ranges": {
                        "start": "135.21.67.150",
                        "end": "135.21.67.170"
                    },
                    "cidr": "135.21.67.128/26",
                    "gateway": "135.21.67.129",
                    "floating_ip_ranges": {
                        "start": "135.21.67.171",
                        "end": "135.21.67.180"
                    }

                },
                "storage": {
                    "ip_ranges": {
                        "start": "192.168.109.100",
                        "end": "192.168.109.200"
                    },
                    "cidr": "192.168.109.0/24"

                },
                "management": {
                    "ip_ranges": {
                        "start": "192.168.27.150",
                        "end": "192.168.27.190"
                    },
                    "cidr": "192.168.27.128/26",
                    "gateway": "192.168.27.129"

                }
            },

            {
                "network_name": "ops_test_network_0",
                "public": {
                    "ip_ranges": {
                        "start": "135.21.67.160",
                        "end": "135.21.67.170"
                    },
                    "cidr": "135.21.67.128/26",
                    "gateway": "135.21.67.129",
                    "floating_ip_ranges": {
                        "start": "135.21.67.171",
                        "end": "135.21.67.180"
                    }

                },
                "storage": {
                    "ip_ranges": {
                        "start": "192.168.109.100",
                        "end": "192.168.109.200"
                    },
                    "cidr": "192.168.109.0/24"

                },
                "management": {
                    "ip_ranges": {
                        "start": "192.168.27.150",
                        "end": "192.168.27.190"
                    },
                    "cidr": "192.168.27.128/26",
                    "gateway": "192.168.9.1"

                }
            }

    ],
```

i want to merge 1list of `dict['name']==public` to 2nd dict key "public"

what is the better way of doing it, 
if there is simpler way the 2nd dict can be modified accordingly
the main question is to map to different list of dict by key `public => public`, `management=>management` .... etc

Comment: Can you provide an example output. Not clear what you want as a result.

Comment: @MikeMüller
if you see the 2nd dict is actually list of dict which contain 0=>'management'>{..}, "public"=>{..}, "storage"=>{...}
so i want to map =0th public to 1 occurence of public in 1st list of dict
1st public to t0 2nd occurence of public in 1st list

Comment: How about adding this information to the question along with a descriptive example?

Answer (score 0):

I have two lists of the same length:

`[1,2,3,4]` and `[a,b,c,d]`

```
dict(zip([1,2,3,4], [a,b,c,d]))
```

If the lists are big you should use `itertools.izip`.

If you have more keys than values, and you want to fill in values for the extra keys, you can use `itertools.izip_longest`.

Here, a, b, c, and d are variables – it will work fine (so long as they are defined), but you probably meant `['a','b','c','d']` if you want them as strings.

`zip` takes the first item from each iterable and makes a tuple, then the second item from each, etc. etc.

`dict` can take an iterable of iterables, where each inner iterable has two items – it then uses the first as the key and the second as the value for each item.